# What kind of licensing is needed for using Windows images with PXE?

Tags: licensing, pxe-boot

I was thinking of using thin clients with PXE booting, using a Windows virtual disk image and CCBoot in Wine on Linux. Even though it is a single Windows image, it may be distrubuted to many clients. With this in mind, what are the Windows licensing requirements for this setup?

As opposed to the possible duplicate this question specifically asks for licensing requirements of PXE boot images. Also the solution to the possible duplicate does not answer my question.

Comment: The linked question specifically states that licensing questions are off topic. The answers explain why.

Comment: Vendors are usually the best source of information for how to license their products.